# Toggling display of divs messes up overflow:scroll

Tags: html, css, overflow, internet-explorer-11, display

I have a modal which is basically:

```
<div class="modal" style="display: block">
    <div class='modal-background'></div>
    <div id='modalContent' class="modal-content" style="max-width:90%;max-height:100%;overflow: scroll;">
        <div onclick='toggleDiv(true)' id="details">
           <h1>Title 1</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut porta quis orci vitae tristique. Proin sit amet fermentum purus, et placerat lacus. Proin efficitur ut metus sit amet tempor. Pellentesque sodales ligula metus, nec volutpat tellus consequat a. Nunc elementum justo eros, ut rutrum leo semper at.</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="update">
           <h1 onclick='toggleDiv(false)'>Title 2</h1>
           <p> Vivamus sit amet ipsum dui. Vestibulum tempus, dui sollicitudin gravida fringilla, lorem velit aliquet nisi, a tempor leo ligula in dolor. Nullam at purus tincidunt, ultrices velit nec, hendrerit nunc. Phasellus molestie ligula eget rhoncus pharetra. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec posuere molestie ullamcorper. Nullam ornare sed justo sed maximus. Proin at eros eget eros vestibulum accumsan.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function toggleDiv(on){
    if(on){
        document.getElementById('update').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('details').style.display = 'none';

    } else{
        document.getElementById('details').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('update').style.display = 'none';
    }

}
</script>
```

This looks fine in IE on first load. But when I try to toggle between the two inner divs .details and .update (by toggling between `display:block` and `display:none`) the modal becomes unscrollable.

Any idea on what is causing this? I've tried using a couple different displays besides block but they seemed to have the same issue.

*works fine in other browsers

Comment: From your code, it seems that you are using Bootstrap, right? when you toggle the two divs, do you change the related CSS style? Besides, please check the content, make sure it will display the scroll. According to the existing code, it is hard to reproduce the problem, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT updated the code snippet to show more of what's roughly going on. The overflow after the toggle works fine in every browser except for IE

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap why wouldn't you just use jQuery's `show()` and `hide()`?

Comment: I'm using bulma, not bootstrap. If I were using jQuery doing `show()` and `hide()` would be roughly the same as what i'm doing here

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a sort of hacky (in my mind) way to resolve this issue. Basically when I go to toggle the divs, I set the overflow to auto before hiding and displaying and then set it back to scroll after. This somehow fixes the issue of the hide/display breaking the overflow.

```
function toggleDiv(on){
    if(on){
        document.getElementById('modalContent').style.overflow = 'auto';
        document.getElementById('update').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('details').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('modalContent').style.overflow = 'scroll';

    } else{
        document.getElementById('modalContent').style.overflow = 'auto';
        document.getElementById('details').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('update').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('modalContent').style.overflow = 'scroll';
    }

}
```